# How to delete a specific node from in a linked list in C?

Tags: c

The following code deletes a particular integer from a list but I want to remove a char array instead. Can anyone help me with how to modify this code so that it deletes a char arr[] instead

```
void removeSpecific(int delValue)
{
    struct node *temp1 = head;  //temp1 Keeps track of the current node
    struct node *temp2 = NULL;  //temp2 Keeps tract of the previous node

    if(temp1->num == delValue)  //Special case: If the item is in the start node
    {
        struct node *temp3 = head; 
        head=head->next;
        free(temp3);         
    }
    else
    { 
        while(temp1->num != delValue) //If the number is not present in the current node
        {                             // we move to the next node
            if(temp1 -> next == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nGiven node not found in the list!!!");
                exit(1); 
            }
            temp2 = temp1;         // Add of 6  next -> 8 ->next  ------- 9
            temp1 = temp1 -> next; // temp1 - Add of 8
        }

        temp2 -> next = temp1 -> next; // removing the node

        free(temp1);
        free(temp2);

        printf("\nOne node deleted!!!\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: Use `strcmp` or `memcmp`

Comment: By the way, why `free(temp2);`?

Comment: The OP says "remove a char array". He/she doesn't say "strings". Therefore, `memcmp()` may be more appropriate than `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a struc with num as a `char[]`, with a needle that is a `char *`, you can use `strcmp`

I move the message out of the else to get it in case of removing the first element

```
void removeSpecific(const char* delValue)
{
    struct node *curr = head;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    if(!strcmp(curr->num, delValue))
    {
        struct node *tmp = head; 
        head=head->next;
        free(tmp);
    } else { 
        while(strcmp(curr->num, delValue)) {
            if(curr -> next == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nGiven node not found in the list!!!");
                exit(1); 
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr -> next;
        }

        prev -> next = curr -> next; // removing the node

        free(curr);
    }
    printf("\nOne node deleted!!!\n\n");

}
```